# Not seeing any Rollup 12 download file? (CRM 2011 On-Premise)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

According to this [Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=2795627) Rollup 12 was suppose to be out last Thursday (Jan 10th 2013).

And they even claim it's out on their download page but I can only see some language and Outlook files.

Am I missing the point?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36229

[Screenshot http://helgi.com/videos/rollup12.JPG](http://helgi.com/videos/rollup12.JPG)

Comment: FYI, I downvoted this question and brought it up @ meta. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163757/are-questions-about-software-update-schedules-availability-on-topic#comment476611_163757, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct. The release was scheduled as you described. However, the server parts got pulled shortly after the release. Until now there is no official statement about the reason or a new date.

Comment: Though it has been released to (some) CRM Online tenants (presumably why the client components are still available).